# dict() vs { } in python which is better?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I like to know, which is the best practice to declare dictionary in below 2 approaches and why?

```
>>>a=dict(one=2, two=3)  # {"two":3, "one":2}
>>>a={"two":3, "one":2}
```

Comment: FWIW, there is one difference I have found.  dict(zip(foo)) is possible.  Not sure why {zip(foo)} is not possible in either python 2 or 3.  I came here hoping to learn why.

Comment: Why is this question closed? People who voted to close it rather could have spent effort to improve it by adding criteria to define `better` instead of closing.

Comment: "Which is better" without defining what "better" means is way to broad

Answer (score 51):

Would you believe [someone has already analyzed that](https://doughellmann.com/posts/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/) (from a performance perspective).

> With CPython 2.7, using dict() to create dictionaries takes up to 6
> times longer and involves more memory allocation operations than the
> literal syntax. Use {} to create dictionaries, especially if you are
> pre-populating them, unless the literal syntax does not work for your
> case.

In 2024, someone else added [a new analysis for Python 3.12](https://madebyme.today/blog/python-dict-vs-curly-brackets/):

> The {} is always faster than dict.

> ```
> $ python -m timeit "dict()"
> 10000000 loops, best of 5: 40 nsec per loop
> $ python -m timeit "{}"
> 20000000 loops, best of 5: 19.6 nsec per loop
> ```

> On my MacBook M1 the difference is almost 2x.

Comment: It's not that surprising considering that keyword arguments are passed as a dictionary that has then to be copied again by the `dict` constructor.

Comment: Anyone up for updating this answer for py 3.7?

Comment: for python3.6 dict() is 2.5 times slower than {}. When pre-populating the difference is 2 times.

Comment: @mahoriR source?

Answer (score 23):

The second one is clearer, easier to read and it's a good thing that a specific syntax exists for this, because it's a very common operation:

```
a = {"two":3, "one":2}
```

And it should be preferred on the general case. The performance argument is a secondary concern, but even so, the `{}` syntax is faster.

Answer (score 15):

In Python you should always use literal syntax whenever possible. So `[]` for lists, `{}` for dicts, etc. It's easier for others to read, looks nicer, and the interpreter will convert it into bytecode that is executed faster (special opcodes for the containers, instead of performing function calls).

Comment: I don't find subjective reasons like "easier for others to read, looks nicer" good arguments :)

Comment: @Matt I think the main take away is " into bytecode that is executed faster", and others are subjective to strengthen the argument, but to echo your sentiment:
`{[(name, cls) for name, cls in dataset_types.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)]}` vs
`dict([(name, cls) for name, cls in dataset_types.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])`, I think the version with `dict()` is much easier to read.

Comment: @Matt I think they are. And as stated in the other comment, there are instances where the non-literal syntax is easier to read. I think it's best to use whatever is easiest to read in each circumstance. But, yes, the literal syntax also has less performance overhead.

Comment: `dict` is "easier to read" than `{}` and the meaning is clearer... especially for those who use multiple languages and find it difficult to remember whether it's braces, brackets, curly braces...

Comment: @Matt - it's actually not subjective. Readability counts is PEP20.

Comment: @jhnwsk - I find `dict(foo=bar)` easier to read and looks more like python to me.

Comment: Me too @Matt, definitely points for dict() for readability and {} for speed. So there is no clear "better". I usually go for dict and optimize if necessary.

Comment: If I pulled someone off the street and asked which creates a list `[]` or `list()`, which do you think most people would guess?